# Scroll handler bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've an bug in my scroll.window jquery script. the function of the script is, when you as visitor scrolls to the bottom the script shows 10 more items, but there is an default. First default is 0 to 10, when you scroll it change to 10 to 20 and after that 20 to 30 etc. etc.

But what the script is doing now is, when i scroll down i get 10 to 20 and when i scroll again i get 20 to 30 and 10 to 20. and what i only need is 20 to 30.

```
function getEvents(first = 0, second = 10) {

var win = $(window);

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '#',
    success : function(data)

    {
        console.log(first,second);
        $.each(data.slice(first,second), function(i, item) {

            content += '{html}';
            $(content).appendTo("#block-a-events");

        })
    }
});

// add counter 
var counter = 1;
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
  // End of the document reached?
  if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
    $('#loading').show();

    getEvents(counter * 10 , ++counter * 10 );

  }
});
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're closing the `getEvents()` function correctly. Add another `}` before `var counter = 1;` and bring `var win = $(window);` after the `getEvents` function:

```js
function getEvents(first = 0, second = 10) {
  // ajax call
  console.log(first);
  console.log(second);
}

var win = $(window);
// add counter 
var counter = 1;
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
  // End of the document reached?
  if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
    getEvents(counter * 10 , (counter + 1) * 10 );
    counter += 2;
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 800px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Scroll up and down
```

Full code:

```
function getEvents(first = 0, second = 10) {

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '#',
    success : function(data)

    {
        console.log(first,second);
        $.each(data.slice(first,second), function(i, item) {

            content += '{html}';
            $(content).appendTo("#block-a-events");

        })
    }
});
}

var win = $(window);
// add counter 
var counter = 1;
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
  // End of the document reached?
  if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
    $('#loading').show();
    getEvents(counter * 10 , (counter + 1) * 10 );
    counter += 2;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work your answer :S I've change it like you said

Comment: @PieterDijkstra please check the edited answer. If I scroll down in the rendered window, the console prints out correct numbers.

Comment: Thanks i saw it. !!